# multiple view controllers strategy

Tags: objective-c, ios6

I am making an app that has about 20 different view controllers that are loaded into a single container view. Some of the views have sliders and buttons and some have only buttons. 
Is there a strategy I can use to make building the views controllers more inline with Objective C coding techniques?

Currently I am trying to combine similar methods into model objects but before I get too involved I thought I'd ask if there is a better way. I'm also willing to do the groundwork and research so any keywords to point me in the right direction would help, i.e. protocols, delegates, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main piece of advice I'd give you is to consider whether or not each one of those view objects needs to be *controlled* at all.  Consider UIViewController like the delegate between the view and the model.  If you don't need an extreme context switch (i.e. pushing a new view onto the navigation stack), then is it really advisable to have 20 delegates floating around?  In most cases, not really.  UIViewController is not a "heavy object" by any stretch of the imagination, but it can quickly make your codebase unwieldy and large if every time you decide to throw a new component onto the screen, you subclass UIViewController.

Try to focus your attention on dividing the logic to setup the view and the actual responsibilities of the controller (reacting to model changes, dispatching operations, updating the view) into a UIView subclass and a UIViewController subclass respectively.  If you truly do need to keep some component of the view separate because its logic simply cannot fit under the main view controller's category of responsibilities, then, and only then, is a new view controller appropriate.